# Responsive lists and the nth-child selector

Tags: html-lists, responsive-design, sass, media-queries, zurb-foundation

I'm having problems understanding nth-child in order to style a list using media queries. I have an unordered list of 6items that displays the items horizontally using `display:inline-block;` in the following manner:

**[item1] [item2] [item3] .... [item6]**

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    li {
        display:inline-block;
        font-size: ms(3);
        padding-left: 0.5em;
        margin-left: 0.5em;
        margin-bottom: 0.2em;
        border-left: 1px dotted #d1d1d1;
        &:first-child {border:none; margin-left:0;};
        a {text-decoration:none;}
```

}

I'm using foundation 3.2 and Sass, and this unordered list resides inside a div of 12 columns. Ideally, I'd like the list to break-down when the browser width is smaller than 768px as follows:

**[item1] [item2] [item3]**

**[item4] [item5] [item6]**

Moreover when the screen is smaller than 320px I'd like the list to display like this:

**[item1] [item2]**

**[item3] [item4]**

**[item5] [item6]**

How can I implement something like this?

Also, I'm using `border-left: 1px dotted #d2d2d2` to make a separator between the list items, while having no border for the first item. How can I utilize nth-child so that in the 768 case I don't get the left-border for both the 1st and 4th items? Additionally, in the 320 case how should I implement nth-child so that there is no left-border in items 1,3 and 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using the CSS Columns module?  It will do all the math for you (paddings, where the divider appears, etc.).  The only problem is that it sorts the items in a different order than what you want.

If you use a column width that is a specific width, it will add/remove columns as necessary for the width of the device without needing media queries.

http://jsfiddle.net/W84Ja/

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
    columns: 8em;
    column-rule: 1px solid;
    column-gap: 2em;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

If you're looking for a percentage style division, use a specific number of columns combined with media queries.

http://jsfiddle.net/W84Ja/1/

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
    columns: 2;
    column-rule: 1px solid;
    column-gap: 2em;
    list-style-type: none;
}

@media (min-width: 25em) {
    ul {
        columns: 3;
    }
}
```

If you're still set on using inline-block list items, this would be the way to do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/W84Ja/2/

```
@media (max-width: 20em) {
    li:nth-child(even) {
        border-left: 1px solid;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 20em) and (max-width: 30em) {
    li:nth-child(3n+2), li:nth-child(3n+3) {
        border-left: 1px solid;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe that css3 columns are for formatting large chunks of text. Additionaly I wanna have images in my list items and right now reading about css3 columns seems like an overkill, since i'm completely unfamiliar with them.
As for your implementation of inline-block items, it doesn't work as it is supposed to. I simply want the list to break into two lines of 3items in the 768px case, and in three lines of two items in the case of 320px.  The list shouldn't break at all in any other case

Comment: There was no mention of images at all in the original question, but CSS columns works fine with them:  http://jsfiddle.net/W84Ja/6/.  The media query only shows which selectors are needed to add the borders to the correct elements.  It's up to you to figure out the math that will make the elements wide enough to force the wrapping to occur.

Comment: I figured out that in the 768px case i need to use nth-child(3n+1) while in the 320px case nth-child(2n+2). Math is tricky in my situation as i will be having images with logos inside the list and the width cannot be predefined. Any ideas?

Comment: If everything is completely unknown (and you don't want to use CSS columns), you have 2 options:  Flexbox http://jsfiddle.net/W84Ja/8/ (prefixes not included) or floats with clears http://jsfiddle.net/W84Ja/9/

Comment: I'm currently trying a flex implementation, but the documentation is scarce, not to mention that the standard has changed numerous times. Trying to figure out how exactly to use -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap; so that the list breaks specifically where I want to.

Comment: This should help you out:  https://gist.github.com/4461470.  Flex-wrap is only for determining whether or not the element wraps or which direction it should wrap.

Comment: Thanx, but i'm really new to Sass, so that code looks a bit incoherent to me (since i lack the experience) Here's an updated fiddle with what i've done http://jsfiddle.net/IgnorantUser/W84Ja/19/
The border-left is working as it should once you reach the breakpoint (items 1 and 4 don't have a left border) what i would like to do is also break the list at the fourth item, but I don't know how

Comment: I'd suggest taking this to chat, but you don't have enough rep yet ><.  The gist is written in the same style as the Compass CSS3 mixins and should work right out of the box if you don't understand the differences between the 3 specs.  The wrap breakpoints are controlled by the `flex-basis` portion of the `flex` property:  `flex: 1 1 30%`.  This translates to "I'm allowed to grow (1st `1`) or shrink (2nd `1`) but I really want to be 30% wide".

Comment: can't really get my head around this thing :/

Comment: Try this:  http://jsfiddle.net/W84Ja/20/.  You'll have to tinker with the flex-basis (flex) a bit and adjust the media queries, but it seems to work right with the sample data.

Comment: Can I also ask what is the suggested fallback for older browsers?
should I use float:left and abandon the list breaking approach for old browser compatibility?

Comment: You can safely use floats or inline-block as a fallback for flexbox.  If the browser supports flexbox, it will ignore the floats completely.

Comment: I'm trying to position the fallback list in the center, but can't manage to do it properly, since positioning will also affect the modern browsers.
Is it possible to have a fallback for display:flex that won't affect modern browsers? Also IE and Safari don't support display:flex, while in Firefox you need to go to about:config and enable it manually, not to mention that it only supports single-line flexbox (info from MDN)

Comment: For what is worth, I found an example of how I want the list to behave
http://www.mutualmobile.com/ check out the "featured partners". From what I saw from their code, they're using display:block and display:inline-block but I simply can't figure out how they make the list break where they want.

Comment: The elements have a width supplied to them, they are using percentages instead of px.  You specified that the width could not be predefined in an earlier comment.